# Current problem

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, circuit-design, mosfet-driver, electrical

I want to control 2 opamps to activate one circuit at a time so I designed an analog selector.

Each circuit works very well. But when I connected them the voltage on the base of T4 jump to 17V. I think I have a current problem but I don't know what to do [image]

Comment: what is an "aop"?

Comment: @MarcusMüller operational amplifier

Comment: changed oap to opamp then; never read aop anywhere else :)

Comment: What does the "a" bit stand for in "aop"?

Comment: @Andyaka I'd guess amplifier, and it might be an abbreviation from French, where abbreviations are often "Noun adjective (NA)" instead of of "adjective Noun (AN)".

Comment: @MarcusMüller it is an abbreviation for amplificateur opérationnel in french

Comment: This isn’t a French speaking website.